# List OL & UL Support for addHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html2canvas, jspdf

Understand so far list (OL & UL) already supported in from html feature (https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/pull/249). May i know is it possible can achieve for addHTML() as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, basically addHTML() can handle anything since it uses [html2canvas](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas) to take "screenshots" of the elements you pass to it, being the result inserted into the PDF through the use of the addImage() function.

Take a look at the following ticket for a little more details on addHTML:

https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/270